# Drupal 8 Contextual Filter Exclude option

Tags: 8, views

I have a case where I want to list all taxonomy terms but exclude the term that is filled in the url. In D7, in contextual filters you could expand 'More' and check that option. I cannot find this option in D8. Am I looking in the wrong place or just not seeing it, or is this option not (yet) in Drupal 8.

If the latter, is there any other option to become this? I searched around but without any succes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, and I got it working because in D8 I didnt have Search API installed(still beta in D8 at time of this post).  Not sure if you have this extension installed.

Also I had to enable Search API term handlers.  Then you should be able to see the Exclude option in the Views contextual filters.

Comment: Thank you very much! Had no idea this option was included in a contributed module.

Answer (score 0):

It can also simply be a visibility issue in the D8 GUI, try collapsing the other sections and/or zoom out in your browser.